# FME discard destructive operations in the table handling drop-down list for PostgreSQL / PostGIS writers

Tags: postgis, postgresql, fme-form, writers

In FME 2023, one can use a PostGIS writer to write some spatial data to a PostGIS database and that's great.

In the table section, one can select one of several Feature Operations:

[image]

When using upsert or insert, there are four way of writing data in the Table Handling drop-down list:

- Use existing
- Create if Needed
- Drop and Create
- Truncate Existing

[image]

Each of those options are nice in some situations. E.g. when the tables do not exist and one want to quickly set these up, the `Create Existing` option is fine. Or one wants to use an existing database structure but resetting the tables, the `Truncate existing` is the best choice.

In a team environment, where several people may manipulate the same workspace in time, is it possible to discard the destructive options to the users so that they are forced to comply with an existing database structure, i.e. to gray out the `Drop and Create` option (and also the `Create if Needed` if need be)?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible in the software. Workaround I can think of is to create a role which can create a table, but not drop it. Have not tested this but I think it is possible.